# What does the option Read Directory Data do if checked?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm creating a ASP.NET Core web application and selected **Work or School Accounts** for authentication.

My questions are:

1. What does the option **Read directory data** mean?
2. What does the option **Read directory data** do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the option **Read directory data** mean?

It means the *delegated permission* `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph`.

> What does the option **Read directory data** do?

If you select the option, it will add the permission  for your `App Registeration` related to the web application in Azure AD(without consent).

[image]

---

For more details about the concept of delegated permission, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types.

About Azure AD Graph, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#permission-scope-details-.

Comment: Is the authentication flow from ```the user``` on the ```web application related to this registered app``` to ```Azure Active Directory Graph``` and back to the ```redirected URL```? What is the result if I don't choose this option? Can I still authenticate?

Comment: @wonderfulworld Yes, if you don‘t choose the option, the user can also auth the app, but you need to add other permission. Even if you select it, you also need to click the admin consent button to grant the permission for your app, otherwise you will get an error when you request the permission.